# How to inject functionality into a C# class without modifying it

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to create a Nuget package that will enable database logging in Entity Framework without actually modifying the existing codebase I'm working with. Is there a way to do that?

Basically, the problem I want to solve is this: I want to make a database logging tool for my company, but I don't want to have to check in any code to the codebase. It would be far easier (e.g. I wouldn't have to convince to create the logging tool or debate that the performance hit is worth it) if I could just optionally slip in the code when I wanted to. Later, people could adopt it if they wanted to, or choose not to.

I mean, of course I could always just have a boolean flag to choose whether or not to log or not, but again, that's touching some core code that might raise some flags with people.

Here's an example of code I want to "slip in":

```
    public DbContext(Func<IIdentity> getUser) : base(getUser)
    {
        // How do I inject this into the constructor?
        this.Database.Log = s =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
            {
                CustomEventLogger.Append(s);
            }
        };
        // end injected code
    }
```

Comment: I'd rather inject an implementation of a logger into the context (by constructor injection) and set `this.Database.Log` if the logger isn't null.

Comment: @GertArnold But wouldn't I need to change the DbContext class to create a constructor that accepts a logger?

Comment: @Slothario If you want to inject functionality into a widget, that widget needs to support having functionality injected into it.

Answer (score 0):

Ask your co-workers to log using [`System.Diagnostics.Trace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=netframework-4.8) and System.Diagnostics.Debug.

You can inject logging to your own system by calling [`Trace.Listeners.Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace.listeners?view=netframework-4.8) or Debug.Listeners.Add.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized a simpler way to do it that would probably be palatable: I could just extend the DbContext class with logging (which, as I didn't mention before, extends an interface) and write code to optionally create it in the dependency injector.

That way, if I wanted my DB logging I could change some flag that only is checked at startup. By default, people would get the regular existing class.